# Please help, FileNotFound Exception among other prblems

Tags: java, arrays, loops, for-loop, filenotfoundexception

I'm utterly lost in Arrays and need help...Here is the end objective of this program....

In a file called AccountArray.java, write a client program (your main method) that reads from the file called customers.txt. Read the first number in the file and create an
array of Account objects, with that number of elements. Use a “for” loop to create an Account object for each line of information you read from the file and store that into an element of the array

Here's where I am at so far... my main concern is the FileNotFound Exception Error.... I have a file named customers.txt saved in the program folder but do I need to initialize it somehow or something?

Any other input regarding things I am doing wrong in this program would be greatly accepted, I'm just beginning to learn this stuff.

```
public class AccountArray {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {



             List<Account> accountsArray = new ArrayList <Account>();


            String name, accountnumber, balance;

            Scanner diskScanner = new Scanner(new File("customers.txt"));
            Scanner scanner= new Scanner ("customers.txt");
            scanner.useDelimiter(" ");
            int objects= scanner.nextInt();
            Account[] accounts=new Account[objects];

            while (objects>0){
                name = scanner.nextLine();
                accountnumber = scanner.nextLine();
                balance = scanner.nextLine();


                   for(int i = 1; i < objects; i++) {
                      accountsArray.add(new Account(i, name, accountnumber, balance));
                   }

                   objects=objects-1;


                   System.out.println(name+ " " + accountnumber + " " + balance +"\n"); }// just for debugging


}
```

}

sample of file :

```
4
John Anderson
4565413
250.00
Louise Carter
2323472
1250.45
Paul Johnson
7267881
942.81
Sarah Wilson
0982377
311.26
```

Comment: Where is " saved in the program folder " in relation to where your  compiled java class is?  The .txt file needs to be in the same directory.

Comment: really new to this, not quite sure what a directory is.... I have a Program called AccountArray with 3 classes and the file

Comment: @user2954611 Do you know what is `relative` and `absolute` path?

Comment: no...I am very new to this

Comment: @user2954611 Read [What Is a Path? (And Other File System Facts)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/path.html). Try to give absolute path of your file. It should be something like `c:\some folder\another folder\file to access` if you are using windows.

Answer (score 1):

Well, first of all, you're using the wrong `Scanner` object:

```
Scanner diskScanner = new Scanner(new File("customers.txt")); // Scans through your file --Use this one
Scanner scanner= new Scanner ("customers.txt"); // Scans through the String "customers.txt" --Not helpful
```

To fix the FileNotFound Exception, you need to move the file customers.txt to the folder that is output by `new File("customers.txt").getAbsoultePath();` as suggested by Freaky Thommi.

You will also run into a few other errors further down, but I'll let you figure those out on your own...

Answer (score 0):

Is this run form eclipse. If yes you need to have this file under your project root folder. You can always find out the absolute path by using

```
new File("customers.txt").getAbsoultePath();
```

Print this to console and see if file is present at this location

Comment: so I have the location....C:\Users\shc115\workspace\AccountArray\customers.txt  but how do I make it read this